# Data is not getting populated in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

```
if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $this->loadModel('Ngolist');
        if($this->Ngolist->save($this->request->data))
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Success");
            $this->redirect(array("action"=>"thoughts"));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Fail");
        }
    }
```

The above is my code to get input from user(with a textarea) and insert/save that to my database 'ngolist' with two fields 'id' and 'thought'.

But am getting the flash with fail? Can anyone help me out with this?

$this->request->data returns
array(
    'NgoLists' => array(
        'thought' => 'hi'
    )
)

Comment: you need to debug better... put `pr($this->Ngolist->validationErrors);` after `$this->Session->setFlash("Fail");` and update your question with the info (if you need to, probably the validation errors will be enough to tell you what's wrong and fix it (and if that happens, please delete this question)).

Comment: Update your question with the value of `debug($this->request->data);`

Comment: @joshua.paling... I have updated the array value

Answer (score 0):

(1)As per the cakephp naming conventions database table name should be ngolists. 
     http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions

(2) If this code is written in NgolistsController.php, then remove this line

`$this->loadModel('Ngolist');` and add the below line,

```
$this->Ngolist->create();
```